# how to test a Model method that uses AuthComponent::user inside

Tags: php, unit-testing, cakephp, mocking, cakephp-2.0

I am using CakePHP 2.4

I have a Model class called Storybook.

There is a method called createDraft and its code looks like this:

```
    public function createDraft($data) {
        $data['Storybook']['author']    = AuthComponent::user('id');
```

When I write a test script using the CakePHP Tests, I have a problem instantiating the user data inside AuthComponent.

My test script looks like this:

```
<?php
App::uses('Storybook', 'Model');
class StorybookTestCase extends CakeTestCase {

/**
 * Fixtures
 *
 * @var array
 */
    public $fixtures = array(...
    );

/**
 * setUp method
 *
 * @return void
 */
    public function setUp() {
        parent::setUp();
        $this->Storybook    = ClassRegistry::init('Storybook');
...
...


/**
 * GIVEN we have only a title
 * WHEN we call createDraft
 * THEN we have a new draft
 *
 * @return void
 */
     public function testCreateDraftSuccessfully() {    
        // GIVEN only a title
        $data = array('Storybook' => array('title' => 'some title'));
        // WHEN we call the createDraft
        $actualResult = $this->Storybook->createDraft($data);
 ....
```

The test failed at createDraft method.

I cannot fill in the AuthComponent with user data at the setUp method since AuthComponent login method is not static.

Please advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The steps I figured out after some googling and asking #cakephp IRC channel:

1) Ensure you are using at least CakePHP 2.3

2) create the following protected function in the AppModel:

```
protected function _getUser($key = null) {
    return AuthComponent::user($key);
}
```

3) ensure that AuthComponent is actually used inside the AppModel:

```
//type this just below App::uses('Model', 'Model');
App::uses('AuthComponent', 'Controller/Component');
```

4) Change the Storybook model to use _getUser instead of AuthComponent::user

```
    public function createDraft($data) {
        $data['Storybook']['author']    = $this->_getUser('id');
```

5) Add the following into the test method courtesy of this [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/testing.html#mocking-model-methods):

```
public function testCreateDraftSuccessfully() {    

        // MOCK the _getUser method to always return 23 because we always expect that
        $this->Storybook = $this->getMockForModel('Storybook', array('_getUser'));
        $this->Storybook->expects($this->once())
        ->method('_getUser')
        ->will($this->returnValue(23));

    // GIVEN only a title
    $data = array('Storybook' => array('title' => 'some title'));
```

That will help you pass the test.

**UPDATE**

If the method you are mocking may return different results depending on different parameters, you need to have another public function that will act as a callback for the mocked method.

Alternative to step 5) Add the following function if you expect to always return 23 if the parameter is 'id' and 1 if the parameter is 'group_id'

```
public function getUserCallBack($field) {
        if ($field == 'id') {
            return 23;
        }
        if ($field == 'group_id') {
            return 1;
        }
    }
```

6) Change the test method to:

```
public function testCreateDraftSuccessfully() {    

        // MOCK the _getUser method to always return 23 for _getUser('id') and 1 for _getUser('group_id')
        $this->Storybook = $this->getMockForModel('Storybook', array('_getUser'));
        $this->Storybook->expects($this->once())
        ->method('_getUser')
        ->with($this->logicalOr(
            $this->equalTo('id'),
            $this->equalTo('group_id')
        ))
        ->will($this->returnCallback(array($this, 'getUserCallBack')));

    // GIVEN only a title
    $data = array('Storybook' => array('title' => 'some title'));
```

[Useful list of matchers for PHPunit.](http://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/test-doubles.html#test-doubles.mock-objects.tables.matchers) E.g.

```
$this->once()
$this->never()
```